# Draw surface of 3D cloud in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, surface

I have 3D cloud  of dots. I need to plot them as a surface. I tried variant with meshdrid, griddata, scatteredInterpolant,trisurf-delaunay. Nothing works. I know that this question was discussed a lot, but it seems I don't understand some important details. The code which i have now:

```
load('coords.mat')
figure()
subplot(1,2,1)
plot3(x,y,z,'.')
axis off
view(3)

subplot(1,2,2)
C=gray(numel(x)); % unsuccessful attempt
[~,idx]=sort(z);  %      to have 
C=C(idx,:);       %    illumination
scatter3(x,y,z,50,C,'filled')
axis off
view(3)
```

produces the following image:
[image]

Could you help me:

**1) to find a way to draw it with surface function.**

and as some dots may be inside the surface (may be it is my problem)

**2) How to remove 'invisible' dots?**

I need solution for different cases, picture and data presents just an example.

Mat file may be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MicR81NQ0A02CQND9ZzKmpUN2eIjkmPw).

## P.S.

*In case it is important – I obtain coordinates of this dots as a rotation of random bezier curve.*

## UPDATE

In case data above is too big I generate another set with smaller amount of dots:

[image]

Coordinates are [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WZh4iufxsPewaK4pBp8S81IlkCF5nscW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where do you get this data from? It is represented as vectors but if you reshape it to matrices you can use the `surf` function. Try this code:

```
z=reshape(z,100,100);
y=reshape(y,100,100);
x=reshape(x,100,100);
surf(x,y,z)
```

Comment: Coool!!! Thanks!! I generate these vectors myself - it is a long and not important code for my question.

Comment: Sorry, but I have stupid problem, far not always x,y,z may be reshaped in square matrix (see second dataset). Should I go via some interpolation?

Comment: @zlon this is why I wanted to talk about where the data originates from =) Your vectors are slices in x directions. This is why reshaped with the size 100x100. Not because it was square number, but because there were 100 slices. In the case of smaller dataset you need to reshape to sizes 100x60. These things are easier to control when you produce the data.