# Convert gridded sphere to dots cloud and back

Tags: matlab, surface

I have a problem with surface generation in matlab. Below is small code. This code looks nonsense, but if It will works I would be happy with my main code :).

```
% create gridded 3D object
[X Y Z]=sphere(1000); 
subplot(1,2,1);
sphere(50) % just for example
% transform it to 3D cloud
X=X(:);
Y=Y(:);
Z=Z(:);
idx=randperm(numel(X),10^3);
X=X(idx);
Y=Y(idx);
Z=Z(idx);
% try to restore surface
F = scatteredInterpolant(X,Y,Z);
[gX,gY]=ndgrid(linspace(min(X),max(X),100),...
    linspace(min(Y),max(Y),100));
gZ=F(gX,gY);
subplot(1,2,2)
surface(gX,gY,gZ)
```

[image]

The problem is: if I have gridded data I may plot sphere (left picture) if my data are just Nx3 array with coordinates of some random dots on the sphere I have right picture.

I had similar question [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770952/draw-surface-of-3d-cloud-in-matlab), but the data were well organised. Could You help me with this? If you have solution on other languages or OpenGL You are welcome!

Comment: "Could You help me with this?" -- please be more specific and explain what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you I just forget pictures and even did not realise it :)

Comment: Would a scatter plot of your data suffice? Something like [`scatter3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html)?

Comment: If not, this is very complicated question! Estimating a surface through a point cloud is possible, but not simple. There's probably MATLAB code for that, though.

Comment: Do you know the points represent a sphere? I ask because fitting a sphere to a point cloud is easier than fitting a general surface.

Comment: They may represent any closed surface. Scatter will be later.